# Check if cells have a checkmark in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app, I am working on something similar to how the normal alarm app allows you to repeat days. In the UITableViewController for repeat days, there are 7 cells for each day in the week(Sunday, Monday, etc). I want to check which cells are checkmarked and then change the text's label(in another viewcontroller) to the cells that are checkmarked(text: Sun, Mon, Tues if sunday, monday, and tuesday cells are checkmarked.)

I tried using a for loop and iterating through each cell, and creating if statements, however there are WAY too many if statements that need to be used here. I would really appreciate it if any of you could show me an easier way to achieve this. Below is a snippet of my code for reference.

```
class RepeatVC: UITableViewController {

    var repeatText: String? = nil //Text to change in this vc and set in other vc

  //  var checked: Bool? = false


    @IBOutlet var repeatView: UITableView! //UITableView in TableViewController

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showRepeat" { //Segue identifier for segue to this viewcontroller

            let displayAddEditAlarm = segue.destination as! AddEditAlarm
            displayAddEditAlarm.repeatLabel.text = repeatText //Text I am trying to change in the other viewcontroller
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark){
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
//         //   checked = false
//            print("\(checked!)")

        }
        else{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
//           // checked = true
//            print("\(checked!)")
        }

//        if(checked == true){
//            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 0){
//                repeatText = "Sunday!"
//                print("\(repeatText!) is the repeated day!!!")
//            }
//        }

    }
```

Here are some pictures explaining what I want:

[image: Checkmark Cells]
[image: Label Text]

Comment: after you selected a cell you need to set `isSelected` property for that cell to `true` or `false` when deselected I believe

Comment: @Lamar could you please write an answer that you think would fit my code. I feel like I would learn much more from that and I would appreciate an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: You need to keep,track of the selected cells in another data structure; I suggest `Set<IndexPath>` or `Set<Int>`. Then you can simply use the contents of the set to determine which days were selected. Don't ever use the cell itself to track state as cells are reused and merely views of your data.

Comment: create a object and there should a property that is  `isSelected`  property for that cell to `true` or `false` .

Comment: @RajatKhare did you figure out or is my answer is helpful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question by doing the following steps. 
I first hooked up a swift file to my uitableviewcontroller.
I then created a variable called weekdays and made it a type of an array of booleans. All 7 values were set to false meaning that none of them are checked at the beginning. Then, in the didSelectRowAt, I set it so that if the checkmark is there and the same cell is selected(meaning it will change to no accessory type), that cell corresponding with a tag would be set to a value of false. I did the vice versa for if it had no accessory type(meaning it would be checked if selected). I then in my prepare for segue, said that if those values were true, then display terms like weekdays, weekends, daily, or the separate days.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RepeatVC: UITableViewController {



    var lastSelection: NSIndexPath!
    var repeatText = ""

    var checked: Bool? = false

    var weekdays: [Bool] = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        self.navigationItem.title = "Repeat"
    }


    @IBOutlet var repeatView: UITableView!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "backFromRepeat" {

            if(weekdays[0] == true){
                repeatText += "Sun "
            }

            if(weekdays[1] == true){
                repeatText += "Mon "
            }

            if(weekdays[2] == true){
                repeatText += "Tue "
            }

            if(weekdays[3] == true){
                repeatText += "Wed "
            }

            if(weekdays[4] == true){
                repeatText += "Thu "
            }

            if(weekdays[5] == true){
                repeatText += "Fri "
            }

            if(weekdays[6] == true){
                repeatText += "Sat "
            }

            if(weekdays[0] == true && weekdays[1] == true && weekdays[2] == true && weekdays[3] == true
                && weekdays[4] == true && weekdays[5] == true && weekdays[6] == true){
                repeatText = "Daily"
            }

            else if(weekdays[0] == true && weekdays[6] == true){
                repeatText = "Weekends"
            }

            else if(weekdays[1] == true && weekdays[2] == true && weekdays[3] == true
                && weekdays[4] == true && weekdays[5] == true){
                repeatText = "Weekdays"
            }
            else if(weekdays[0] == false && weekdays[1] == false && weekdays[2] == false && weekdays[3] == false
                && weekdays[4] == false && weekdays[5] == false && weekdays[6] == false){
                repeatText = "Never"
            }

            let displayAddEditAlarm = segue.destination as! AddEditAlarm
            displayAddEditAlarm.repeatLabel.text = repeatText
            print("\(repeatText) is my text")
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark){
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 0){
                weekdays[0] = false
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 1){
                weekdays[1] = false
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 2){
                weekdays[2] = false
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 3){
                weekdays[3] = false
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 4){
                weekdays[4] = false
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 5){
                weekdays[5] = false
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 6){
                weekdays[6] = false
            }
        }
        else{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 0){
                weekdays[0] = true
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 1){
                weekdays[1] = true
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 2){
                weekdays[2] = true
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 3){
                weekdays[3] = true
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 4){
                weekdays[4] = true
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 5){
                weekdays[5] = true
            }
            if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 6){
                weekdays[6] = true
            }
            print(weekdays)

        }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you want stuff to "respond" to actions, you can think of `delegates` or `NotificationCenter`

Check this simple tutorial on how to make delegates work for you
https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/

in summary, when a user checks a day, your label.text will change

Comment: Just to clarify, could you see my reviewed and edited post.